# Link is not working when clicked from phone

Tags: html, css, href

I have the code below, and the link is not working when loading the webpage from a phone(it only works in desktop mode). Any help please? (below is also the css code, the page is styled on the same file, but that is irrelevant). I click the link from the computer, and it works. I click it from mobile phone, it does not work. NOTE!!! Go to dogger.onlinewebshop.net to see the project <dogger.onlinewebshop.net>

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Acasa | Dogger.ro </title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #793698;
                height: device-height;
                width: device-width;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            .main{
                width: 30%;
                margin-left: 35%;
                height: 150px;
                line-height: 100%;
                margin-top: 200px;
            }
            
            .main h1{
                color: #fff;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 50px;
            }
            
            .main a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
            }
            
            .main a{
                height: 50px;
                font-size: 30px;
                                font-family: sans-serif;
                margin-top: 5px;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #fff;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #793698;
                width: 150px;
                                display: inline-block;
                                padding-top: 25px;
                
            }
            
            .main a:hover{
                background-color: #6a2f85;
            }
            
            .adspace img{
                margin-top: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                width: 60%;
                border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
                        @media only screen and (max-width:1080px){
                                .main{
                                        margin-top: 50%;
                                }
                                
                                .main h1{
                                        font-size: 100px;
                                }
                                
                                .main a{
                                        height: 100px;
                                        font-size: 50px;
                                        margin-top: 100px;
                                        width: 300px;
                                        padding-top: 75px;
                                }
                                .adspace img{
                                        float: bottom;
                                        margin-top: 85%;
                                        width: 80%;
                                        height: 120px;
                                }
                        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "main">
            <h1> dogger </h1>
            <a href = "main.php"> enter </a>
        </div>
        <div class = "adspace">
            <img src = "https://picsum.photos/1200/200">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div called `adspace` (the picture) is blocking the button, (it is in front of it). You need to style it to be shorter using CSS `height`, or you can push it to the back using CSS `z-index`.